# Trouble navigating to main class with Heroku/Procfile

Tags: java, heroku

I am trying to navigate to my main class file in order to host it through Heroku but I cannot seem to navigate to it through my Procfile.

```
   2020-07-14T00:26:21.819970+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -cp target/classes/com/marcuzzo/JDABot Bot.class`
    2020-07-14T00:26:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2020-07-14T00:26:23.780252+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
    2020-07-14T00:26:23.783762+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    2020-07-14T00:26:23.872167+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class Bot.class
    2020-07-14T00:26:23.928585+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2020-07-14T00:26:23.978108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2020-07-14T00:26:23.982448+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2020-07-14T00:26:26.759237+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -cp target/classes/com/marcuzzo/JDABot Bot.class`
    2020-07-14T00:26:29.372233+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
    2020-07-14T00:26:29.378057+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    2020-07-14T00:26:29.489053+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class Bot.class
    2020-07-14T00:26:29.564012+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2020-07-14T00:26:29.609043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Procfile: `web: java -cp target/classes/com/marcuzzo/JDABot Bot.class`

POM File:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.marcuzzo</groupId>
  <artifactId>JDABot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>JDABot</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0_178</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>jcenter</id>
    <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
</repository>
  </repositories>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.marcuzzo.JDABot</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Even though my main class path is target/classes/com/marcuzzo/JDABot/Bot.class it doesn't seem to be able to find it. Can anyone tell me why this is?

EDIT:
Directory = `C:\Users\mattm\Desktop\Projects\JDABot`
Path of Bot.class:
`C:\Users\mattm\Desktop\Projects\JDABot\target\classes\com\marcuzzo\JDABot`

```
EDIT: Heroku Logs

     2020-07-14T01:15:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mattmarcuzzo@gmail.com
2020-07-14T01:16:11.013386+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 3b17fa92 by user mattmarcuzzo@gmail.com
2020-07-14T01:16:11.013386+00:00 app[api]: Release v43 created by user mattmarcuzzo@gmail.com
2020-07-14T01:16:11.546025+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-07-14T01:16:13.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-07-14T01:16:14.216417+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh -c "java -cp target/classes/ com.marcuzzo.JDABot"`
2020-07-14T01:16:16.606060+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-07-14T01:16:16.619387+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2020-07-14T01:16:16.757017+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class com.marcuzzo.JDABot
2020-07-14T01:16:16.820083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-07-14T01:16:16.859983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-07-14T01:16:16.862873+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-07-14T01:16:20.017311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh -c "java -cp target/classes/ com.marcuzzo.JDABot"`
```

EDIT:

```
C:\Users\mattm\Desktop\Projects\JDABot\target\classes\com\marcuzzo\JDABot

07/13/2020  07:17 PM    <DIR>          .
07/13/2020  07:17 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/13/2020  07:10 PM               782 Bot.class
               1 File(s)            782 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  39,904,493,568 bytes free`
```

Comment: Use `java -cp target/classes/com/marcuzzo/JDABot Bot` instead.

Comment: If you have a pom it may be simpler to use the maven exec plugin.

Comment: @PiRocks yea i just posted my POM a few seconds ago and am using org.apache.maven.plugin. Not sure if that is the same tho but your earlier suggestion did not work

Comment: Your manifest in the pom describes a main class of `com.marcuzzo.JDABot`, while your Procfile describes a main class with no package, called `Bot`. Can you show us your full file layout etc.

Comment: @PiRocks I have posted the file directory path and the path leading to Bot.class. I do not know an easy way to put the full paths of all my directory files though

Comment: Going by the newest edit you want something like: `java -cp target/classes/ com.marcuzzo.JDABot`. Any jars will have to be added manually to the classpath. You can list directories with the unix commands `lstree` or `ls -R`, not aware of anything for windows.

Comment: Sorry my last comment was slightly wrong, I've edited it to fix that

Comment: that did not seem to work. Also, when I am pushing it to Heroku it is building the .jar file so I do not think I have to add them manually but I am not 100% on that @PiRocks

Comment: Been a while since I used heroku, but there should be a way to show stdout/error log. Can you post that?

Comment: I have posted the log of `web: java -cp target/classes/com.marcuzzo.JDABot`  Do you think it is my POM? @PiRocks

Comment: That's interesting have you tried something like sh -c "java..."

Comment: As in `web: sh -c java -cp target/classes/com.marcuzzo.JDABot` ? @PiRocks

Comment: Needs quotes around the java command. The error indicates that some of the parameters aren't getting to java, so I'm wrapping it in a subshell.

Comment: To clarify the quotes need to be around java and the java arguments

Comment: @PiRocks Right. I tried `web: sh -c "java -cp target/classes/com.marcuzzo.JDABot"` but it didnt seem to work either. Log posted

Comment: Needs a space between classes/ and package name

Comment: Using `web: sh -c "java -cp target/classes/ com.marcuzzo.JDABot"` Brings me right back to the `Could not find or load main class com.marcuzzo.JDABot`. Full log posted @PiRocks

Comment: Okay this raises the question: are you sure your main class is in fact there?

Comment: @PiRocks It definitely is. I posted the `dir` on com/marcuzzo/JDABot

Comment: So there maybe something different happening within the heroku filesystem, are you sure your building properly etc? . If you can build and run a jar locally I would try that, and then try running it on heroku. Another option would be to throw everything into a dockerfile.

Comment: @PiRocks To be honest I do not know how to test it locally. Or how to put it all in a dockerfile

Comment: Are you following some kind of tutorial?

Comment: @PiRocks Well before i followed a tutorial on how to host a python (discord) bot and it worked perfectly. Then something happened with my python files. All messed up now. So I thought I would try it with java, my main language, since it worked so well with python. For java, I have followed various posts/heroku web pages so not just one single tutorial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217764/discussion-between-pirocks-and-matt).